# Movie/series where the whole crew of a spaceship and the ship itself are dissolving

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm looking for a TV series episode or a movie (more likely to be an episode) which I have seen many years ago (early 2000s, but could be older).

The crew of a spaceship gets sick without a reason one after another and they are dissolving/dying. They try to find a cure but without success. Somehow the ship is unable to maneuver and is stuck in its position. They manage to send an SOS signal, which is noticed by another ship coming to their position. When they arrive, the whole ship itself has dissolved and left nothing behind, and the rescue ship wonders what may have happened here. Plot twist was that the ship coming to rescue them was the very same ship that initially had the problems, so one of both must have been doppelgangers or something like that.

I believe it might have been from *Star Trek* or *Stargate* but can't find anything about it.

Comment: I can confirm that while Stargate has seen [many](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Tin_Man), [many](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Replicator_Carter), [many](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Ripple_Effect) duplicates of the cast, and less frequently of the [ships](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Daedalus_Variations), there were thankfully no instances of them gradually dissolving.

Answer (score 35):

Likely this is the Star Trek: Voyager episode [*Course: Oblivion*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Course:_Oblivion_(episode))

The crew of the first ship realise that they're 'silver blood duplicates' from an [earlier episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)) and desperately try to make contact with their flesh and blood counterparts but

> [fail](https://youtu.be/2jq70Zo9M-g?t=284)

Comment: I found this to be the saddest VOY episode.  If the writers were ever to revisit the silver-blood duplicates, I'd hoped they'd do something more fun with them, like have them establish a whole civilization.  Instead, they "dissolve", and the end result is precious close to that bad-writing trope, "but it was all a dream..."  :(

Comment: I read it differently. These people were given sapience by voyager's crew. They lived, had adventures, and touched peoples lives in the worlds they visited. The story is tragic because voyager's crew will never know their impact on the biomemetic lifeforms and will never know how those lifeforms impacted the people in the delta quadrant or how they died trying to get home. Not only that, had they gotten there in time, they could've saved them and found the enhanced warp drive to get home much sooner than they did. This is a very tragic episode all around because it wasn't all just a dream.